# How to split streaming video into pieces FFMPEG

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, streamlink

I have a bat script (Windows) for the library Livestreamer to record the broadcast in the video

```
:loop

set day=%DATE:~0,2%
set month=%DATE:~3,2%
set year=%DATE:~6,4%

set hour=%TIME:~0,2%
set minute=%TIME:~3,2%
set second=%TIME:~6,2%

set YYYYMMDD=%day%_%month%_%year%_%hour%_%minute%_%second%


streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 1024M -o %YYYYMMDD%.ts https://www.twitch.tv/silvername best
goto loop
```

How can I break this video into pieces?

I tried to do so, but it did not work, writes the error of the arguments

```
ffmpeg -i "streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 1024M -o %YYYYMMDD%.ts https://www.twitch.tv/manyrin best" -f segment -segment_time 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%03d.ts"
```

Comment: You should input the streamlink output TS file to ffmpeg, not the command.

Comment: @Gyan Did not quite understand you, can you tell me the code?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "%YYYYMMDD%.ts" -f segment -segment_time 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%03d.ts"` where `%YYYYMMDD%.ts` is the name of the file that streamlink saved

Comment: @Gyan You did not understand, I need to break the video while the broadcast is on, and you suggested that I break it when it was already finished and the file was created

Comment: MPEG-TS is a transport format. You can feed it to ffmpeg while it is being saved by streamlink.

Comment: @Gyan well, like this "streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 1024M -o test.ts https://www.twitch.tv/manyrin best" just saves to file, bun i am get error  "streamlink --hls-live-edge 99999 --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 1024M -o test.ts https://www.twitch.tv/sharishaxd best: Invalid argument"

Comment: @Gyan So, is it possible to divide the broadcast while recording?